# Page margins and distance from the border

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry, border

I have to write an official document following some precise instructions:

- top margin: 3;
- bottom margin: 2.5;
- left margin 2.5;
- right margin: 2.5;
- header distance from border: 1.25;
- footer distance from border: 1.25;

The thing is, I can't find the right commands to do it.

By far, I have written this:

```
\geometry{vmargin={3cm,2.5cm}}
\geometry{hmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}}
```

How can I add the header and the footer's distances from the border?

Looking online, I found this:

```
\geometry{top = 1.25cm, bottom = 1.25cm}
```

but I don't think it works properly.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: See illustration  in geometry documentation, page 3 figure 1: show, how you still can use  `headsep` and `headheight` (if needed), and `footskip`. For your example, if I correctly understood your descriotion of page layout:: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm},vmargin={3cm,2.5cm},
            headheight=1.25cm, 
            %headsep=1.25cm,
            footskip=1.25cm,
            showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
hello!
\end{document}
`

Comment: Dear @Zarko, thanks for you answer! I'm trying to use it as it is in my file. I don't know why, but now it gives me error on the following lines ```
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{es}{Esempio}[chapter]``` Do you think these are correlated? By removing your line it doesn't give me any error

Comment: No it is not correlated. For more help we need to see an file example which reproduce your problem. Ask new question and show it.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It should be noted that the definition of top and bottom changes with nohead, nofoot and/or noheadfoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (precision better than 0.1mm): demo with a4 paper:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2.5cm, top=3cm, headsep=1.75cm, footskip=1.25cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It gives me this error: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.54 \geometry
              {margin=2.5cm, top=3cm, headsep=1.25cm, footskip=1.25cm}

Comment: You have the error for this very document?

Comment: No, for mine. I just copy part of your lines into mine

Comment: This means `geometry` is already loaded by another package , or your document class with other options. Could you post a minimal example code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I accidentaly wrote it in another part of the document. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to feel helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go old school:

The 1in top and side margin is built into the TeX engine itself.

```
\setlength{\topmargin}{\dimexpr 1.25cm-1in}
\setlength}\headsep}{\dimexpr 3cm-1in-\topmargin-\headheight}
\setlength{\textheight}{\dimexpr \paperheight-3cm-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep}
\setlength{\footskip}{\paperheight-1.25cm-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\dimexpr 2.5cm-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}% both oneside and twoside, in this case
\setlength{\textwidth}{\dimexpr \paperwidth-2.5cm-1in-\oddsidemargin}
```